# Integral homology group of a 3-torus cut out a donut

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, geometric-topology

I know that the integral homology group of the manifold $M$ is given by 
$$
H_j(M,\mathbb{Z})
$$

I also have tried that $H_j(T^3,\mathbb{Z})$ is given by
$$
H_0(T^3,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z},
$$
$$
H_1(T^3,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^3,
$$
$$
H_2(T^3,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^3,
$$
$$
H_3(T^3,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z},
$$

> Could we or could you suggest how to derive $H_j(T^3 - D^2 \times S^1,\mathbb{Z})=?$ In particular $j=0,1,2,3$. Mostly:
>   $$
> H_1(T^3- D^2 \times S^1,\mathbb{Z})=?,
> $$
>   $$
> H_2(T^3- D^2 \times S^1,\mathbb{Z})=?,
> $$
>   where we choose the $T^3=S^1_x \times S^1_y \times S^1_z$ of three circles. And we choose that $ D^2 \times S^1= D^2 \times S^1_z$ where its circle is along the same circle as $S^1_z$ of $T^3$, while the $D^2$ is a tiny 2-disk.

So by $T^3- D^2 \times S^1$, we make a **small tubular neighborhood cut along a chosen $S^1_z$ circle**, cut out from the $T^3$.

Thank you. <3

Comment: I don't understand what are you actually cutting out. Is it the set $\{(e^{it_1},e^{it_2},e^{it_3}) \in T^3\; |\; t_1^2 + t^2_2 < \delta \}$ for some small $\delta$?

Comment: yes, and for arbitrary $t_3$. I think I know the answer...

Comment: Yeah, it deformation retracts to $S^1$.

Comment: what is your answer? $\mathbb{Z}^3$ for H_1 and $\mathbb{Z}^2$ for H_2?

Comment: OK, let me write a proper answer.

Comment: Your space is homotopy equivalent to the product of $S^1$ with $S^1\vee S^1$. Now, use the Kunneth formula to compute homology.